# Multithreading to find count file parallelly using Python

Tags: python, multithreading

i have a code to check count of files in a folder  and other details of folder using python , since i wanted to make it a little fast , i included multithreading concept to count the file whenever it comes across any directory / folder inside root folder , like it will assign a thread which will count the number of file to a directory whenever it gets a directory . The program created is working fine . But think it is working sequentially rather than parallely .

so here is my code :

```
root =  roots = 'C:/Users/'
count_of_file = 0


noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0

def Count_files_in_subd():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(roots):
        taggedrootdir = pathlib.Path(root)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=findfiles, args=(taggedrootdir,files,))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()


def findfiles(taggedrootdir,files):
    folderstat = {}
    folderstat['FolderPath'] = root
    folderstat['count'] = len(files)

    print(folderstat)


start_time = time.time()
Count_files_in_subd()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and how will i use the same script for shared path

Comment: The Python interpreter has a global interpreter lock (GIL) which limit one thread of execution at a time. So, you will not gain performance for CPU bound task. Only I/O tasks, (or other tasks that release the GIL) will benefit from multithreading

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Python has a concept called the "global interpreter lock" that only allows one thread at a time to be executing Python code.  The only way there's a real win is if you have threads waiting for I/O, or are executing in a C library that manages things itself.

Having said that, enumerating through directories in Windows is never a fast task.  I've written basically this same tool in C++, and it just takes time.  Threading doesn't help when you are I/O bound.

Comment: Yeah , am not writing anything to disk . Am just fetching the count right

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `Pool` object from the [multiprocessing
library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Your code modified:

```
import os, time
from   multiprocessing import Pool

def findfiles(taggedrootdir,files):
    folderstat = {}
    folderstat['FolderPath'] = taggedrootdir
    folderstat['count'] = len(files)

    return folderstat

if __name__ == '__main__':

    roots = r'C:/Users/'

    start_time = time.time()

    args = ((root, files) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(roots))

    for result in Pool().starmap(findfiles, args):
        print(result)

    print('--- %s seconds ---' % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Running this on my python installation folder tree takes `0.5` seconds compared to `21.8` with your version.

Comment: how to do it with shared path

Comment: You would find that this is even faster without the Pool. The use of multiprocessing here is pure overhead as the worker function does nothing.

Comment: what's the advantage of using this over multi threading